# properties of const TYPE* const VAR

Tags: c, pointers, constants

I am trying to understand the following situation:

We have a declaration of a const variable `pfPowerManStates` of type pointer to const `PowerManStateType`.
`PowerManStateType` is a function pointer - `uint8 (*PowerManStateType)(void);`
In other words, `pfPowerManStates` is a const pointer to a const variable of type funciton pointer. 
definition of `pfPowerManStates`:

```
const PowerManStateType* const pfPowerManStates = &(pfStates[0]);
```

And it points to an array full of function pointers

So far so good. But later I see the following statement:

```
NewPowerModeL = pfPowerManStates[CurrentPowerMode]();
```

Here we assign the value of `pfPowerManstate` to some variable.
So, I can't wrap it around my head.
Doesn't having the two `const` keywords in the declaration mean that we can only READ the very
first value of the array `(&(pfStates[0])`? 
My understanding is the following:
I have a const pointer of type const pointer to function that takes (void) arguments and returns an int.
For its declaration, this const pointer receives the value of the adress of the first function in the array of functions `pfStates[X]` and because its const, we cannot point to another function in the array `pfStates[X]`. 
I am very confused at this point,  read the post 5 times and got even more confused, so I will just post it and hope for the best. 
Thank you.

Comment: provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're calling the function, and assigning the return value aren't you? Those little parens at the end of the line matter.

Comment: Don't post images of text, copy-paste the text as text instead. I want to copy-paste some "text" into an answer, but it's impossible because it's an image.

Comment: yes i believe so. But how come i am calling a different function, isn't the pointer const to exactly the first one only?

Comment: Sorry i was not aware of that. Can i edit the post or i do not have this option?

Comment: There's an `edit` link right below the line of tags.

Comment: Done. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short summary:

```
const T *p;  // p is writable, *p is not
T const *p;  // same as above
```

The *expression* `*p` has type `const T`, so you cannot assign a new value to `*p` (you can't write to the thing `p` points to).  However, you can assign a new value to `p`, setting it to point to a different `const T` object. `p` is a non-`const` pointer to a `const` object.

```
T * const p; // *p is writable, p is not
```

The expression `*p` has type `T`, so it's writable - you can update the value of what `p` points to.  However, the pointer `p` itself has type `T * const`, so it cannot be written to - you cannot set `p` to point to a different object. `p` is a `const` pointer to a non-`const` object.

```
const T * const p; // neither p nor *p are writable
T const * const p; // same as above
```

In this case, `*p` has type `const T` and `p` has type `const T * const` - neither can be written to.  `p` is a `const` pointer to a `const` object.

In this particular case:

```
const PowerManStateType* const pfPowerManStates = &(pfStates[0]);
```

`pfPowerManStates` points to the *first element* of an array of what appear to be function pointers.  Since `pfPowerManStates` is itself a pointer, you can use the `[]` operator on it like an array and thus *read* elements from the array.  However, you cannot modify any of the elements through `pfPowerManStates`, nor can you set it to point to a different object.

Comment: This made it really clear. I was too much in my head and couldn't view it this way. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
NewPowerModeL = pwPowerManStates[CurrentPowerMode]();
```

can be broken up into smaller parts:

```
PowerManStateType temporary_function_pointer = pwPowerManStates[CurrentPowerMode];
NewPowerModeL = temporary_function_pointer();
```

So you don't assign the value of `pwPowerManStates` to the `NewPowerModeL` variable, instead you dereference the `pwPowerManStates` pointer to get a single element. This element is a pointer to a function. And then you call this function to get the value to assign to `NewPowerModeL`.

---

Also note that

```
NewPowerModeL = pwPowerManStates[CurrentPowerMode]();
```

should be equivalent to

```
NewPowerModeL = pfStates[CurrentPowerMode]();
```

Answer (score 1):

`const` pointer does not prevent it to be indexed (ie. used as array) or used in the pointer arithmetic. You can't  only change the pointer itself.

Below you have a bit more easy to understand code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

const int *const constptr = array;

int pick(const int *const ptr, int index)
{
    return ptr[index];
}

int pick1(const int *const ptr, int index)
{
    return *(ptr + index);
}

int main()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]); x++)
    {
        printf("x = %d constptr[%d] == %d\n", x, x, pick(constptr, x));
        printf("x = %d constptr + %d == %d\n", x, x, pick1(constptr, x));
    }
}
```